# Store and compare last two lines using response.iter_lines()

Tags: python, stream, iterator

I have a rate stream where I need to store and compare the last two lines.  For instance if the new price is higher than the previous, queue event.  It's my understanding that `iter_lines()`only displays the last line.  My question is how could I store the last line, wait for a new line and compare those, then queue the event?  I know this is simple, but I'm still having trouble, thanks for your help!

Here is my UPDATED(3) stream:

```
def stream_to_queue(self):
    response = self.connect_to_stream()
    if response.status_code != 200:
        return
    oldLine = ''    
    for line in response.iter_lines(1):

        if line < oldLine:
            try:
                msg = json.loads(line)
            except Exception as e:
                print "Caught exception when converting message into json\n" + str(e)
                return
            if msg.has_key("instrument") or msg.has_key("tick"):
                print msg["tick"]
                instrument = msg["tick"]["instrument"]
                time = msg["tick"]["time"]
                bid = msg["tick"]["bid"]
                ask = msg["tick"]["ask"]
                stop = msg["tick"]["ask"]
                tev = TickEvent(instrument, time, bid, ask)
                self.events_queue.put(tev)
        oldLine = line
```

Comment: I don't know how that stream works, but could you initialize an `old_line = ''` variable before the `for` loop, and then inside the for loop compare `old_line` with `line` and assign `line` to `old_line`?

Comment: That might work..  Its just a steady stream from an API..  So if i simply store the line before the loop then I can compare in the loop and it won't be comparing the same line?

Comment: My suggestion is to store the line inside the loop. You just need to initialize the variable before the loop so the first comparison doesn't throw an exception (because `old_line` wouldn't exist yet). After comparing you assign `old_line = line`.

Comment: ok, I understand, I'll give it a shot real quick..  Thanks for the help..  I'll post my attempt

Comment: I've updated my example, is that how you would implement?  or am I still missing it?

Comment: `old_line = line` would have to be just one indentation level below the `for`, so it happens on every line. And I would expect the comparison to be something other than `line > old_line`, but I suppose that's just an example. Be careful to always use the same variable name too, whether it's `oldLine` or `old_line`.

Comment: It sort of works when I run it like above, however, since I don't think I am actually storing a value for 'oldLine' yet its letting everything go through due to the fact that there is no value.  When I switch to '<' it stops..  which is good I guess

Comment: ok, l'll give that a go real quick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88214/discussion-between-paulo-almeida-and-macd).

Answer (score 0):

The original function:

```
def stream_to_queue(self):
    response = self.connect_to_stream()
    if response.status_code != 200:
        return
    for line in response.iter_lines(1):
        if line:
            try:
                msg = json.loads(line)
            except Exception as e:
                print "Caught exception when converting message into json\n" + str(e)
                return
            if msg.has_key("instrument") or msg.has_key("tick"):
                print msg["tick"]
                instrument = msg["tick"]["instrument"]
                time = msg["tick"]["time"]
                bid = msg["tick"]["bid"]
                ask = msg["tick"]["ask"]
                stop = msg["tick"]["ask"]
```

The repaired function:

```
def stream_to_queue(self):
    response = self.connect_to_stream()
    if response.status_code != 200:
        return
    last_msg = None   # new line
    for line in response.iter_lines(1):
        if line:
            try:
                msg = json.loads(line)
                if last_msg is None:   # new line
                    last_msg = msg     # new line
            except Exception as e:
                print "Caught exception when converting message into json\n" + str(e)
                return
            # can now compare last msg with current msg
            if msg.has_key("instrument") or msg.has_key("tick"):
                print msg["tick"]
                instrument = msg["tick"]["instrument"]
                time = msg["tick"]["time"]
                bid = msg["tick"]["bid"]
                ask = msg["tick"]["ask"]
                stop = msg["tick"]["ask"]
            last_msg = msg   # new line (may want to indent 4 more spaces)
```

It may make sense to move the `if last_msg is None` check to the inside of `if msg.has_key` block if you want the `last_msg` to have certain information.